# MariaDB does not accept specific date as 'default on update' value

Tags: sql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 10.5.8.

The following commands work :

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT '2100-01-01 00:00:000' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

But the following command does not work :

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE '2100-01-01 00:00:000'
);
```

It returns `` ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`2100-01-01 00:00:000`  )' at line 1 ``.

Comment: Check the [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#column-definitions): *[ON UPDATE [NOW | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] [(precision)]]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#default-column-option) is really clear on what syntax is allowed:

```
[ON UPDATE [NOW | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP] [(precision)]]
```

This does not include putting in a custom value.

To be honest, I'm not sure if the designers would have even considered a constant value for such a column.  After all, you can just have two columns and check an update if `updatedAt <> createdAt`.

Comment: My bad, I was so sure it was a syntax problem in my code and not a mariadb limitation, that I did not consult the documentation. Thanks !